# Why is PostgreSQL not finding my newly created database

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-10

I'm an absolute noob in PostgreSQL and I am trying to do some things. My current experiment is to do some backups. I run

```
psql -h /tmp -p 6773 -d postgres
```

here I create a database called backups:

```
CREATE DATABASE backups;
```

I quit from this:

```
\q
```

and now I run

```
pgbench -i backups
```

however, this gives me an error:

```
connection to database "backups" failed:
FATAL:  database "backups" does not exist
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You forgot the `-h` and `-p` option.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe you are great, man! Thank you. The command I actually ran was pgbench -h /tmp -p 6773 -d postgres -i backups and it worked. I will continue my experimenting on Monday, but thank you, I had lost a ridiculously lot of time researching this probably simple question. If you post an answer I will be more than happy to accept. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All PostgreSQL client programs take the same connection options:

- `-h` for the host
- `-p` for the port
- `-U` for the user

Some programs use `-d` for the database, some need the database as an argument to the command.

In your case, since you used a non-default `-h` and `-p` option to connect with `psql`, you should use the same options for `pgbench`.